# gitlab backup : no timestamp for backup filesnames

Tags: backup, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

Doing my gitlab backup the backuped files have:

- no timestamp

  - should be like this: `The filename will be [TIMESTAMP]_gitlab_backup.tar`

here the files::

```
root@gitlab:~# ll /mnt/backup-git/ -h
total 1.9G
-rw------- 1 git  git   57M Nov 29 15:57 1480431448_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw------- 1 git  git   57M Nov 29 15:57 1480431473_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw------- 1 git  git  452M Nov 30 02:00 1480467623_gitlab_backup.tar
```

Here my configuration values for the backup::

```
$ grep -i backup /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb | grep -v '^#'
gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = "/mnt/backup-git/"
gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800
```

To create them, following the documentation [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md), (omnibus installation):

```
root@gitlab:~# crontab -l | grep -v '^#'
0 2 * * * /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create CRON=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files clearly have a timestamp already:

**1480431448**_gitlab_backup.tar

The bold is the [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for the backup